# Centrar botones y TxtPane

Tags: java, eclipse, aplicación-escritorio

estoy empezando a usar Eclipse para hacer una aplicación de escritorio y estoy algo pez.

Me gustaría saber como puedo encontrar la forma que al ampliar la pantalla el resto de objetos también se desplacen.
Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

mi código es el siguiente:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class pantalla_frame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtUsuari2;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pantalla_frame frame = new pantalla_frame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public pantalla_frame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 995, 670);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTextPane txtUsuari = new JTextPane();
        txtUsuari.setText("USUARI");
        txtUsuari.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        txtUsuari.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        txtUsuari.setBounds(317, 71, 284, 96);
        txtUsuari.setEditable(false);       
        StyledDocument doc = txtUsuari.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
        contentPane.add(txtUsuari);

        txtUsuari2 = new JTextField();
        txtUsuari2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtUsuari2.setBounds(317, 178, 284, 38);
        contentPane.add(txtUsuari2);
        txtUsuari2.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane txtpnPassword = new JTextPane();
        txtpnPassword.setText("PASSWORD");
        txtpnPassword.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        txtpnPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        txtpnPassword.setBounds(317, 227, 284, 96);
        txtpnPassword.setEditable(false); 
        contentPane.add(txtpnPassword);
        StyledDocument doc2 = txtpnPassword.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center2 = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center2, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc2.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc2.getLength(), center2, false);
        contentPane.add(txtpnPassword);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField.setBounds(317, 334, 284, 45);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btn_aceptar = new JButton("ACEPTAR");
        btn_aceptar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btn_aceptar.setBounds(317, 434, 284, 45);
        contentPane.add(btn_aceptar);

        JTextPane txtpnGamnificacioc = new JTextPane();
        txtpnGamnificacioc.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        txtpnGamnificacioc.setText("GamnificacIOC");
        txtpnGamnificacioc.setBounds(0, 0, 208, 71);
        contentPane.add(txtpnGamnificacioc);
    }
}
```

Comment: que yo sepa lo tienes que hacer tú, tienes que mantener la relación entre la posición de los elementos y el ancho del formulario.. Tienes que ir jugando con la posición del botón

Comment: vale.. no sé como se hace seguiré buscando. Gracasi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me intento explicar un poco mejor porque mi comentario...

Pongo de ejemplo la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenemos un formulario de anchura 100 px, un Datagrid que empieza en el pixel 50 y de ancho ocupa 50 px.

Si queremos que, al agrandar el formulario se agrande el datagrid se hace lo siguiente:

> Datagrid.width = form.width - 50px

Esto hay que ponerlo en el método resize del formulario.
Habría que hacer lo mismo con la altura puesto que con este código solo crecería a lo ancho.

Sería igual si lo que te preocupa, en vez de ancho o alto, es la posición, en vez de el ancho, tendrías que modificar el atributo Left en vez del ancho.

Espero haberme explicado bien.